# Get Array of All Possible l33t Combinations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, prototype, str-replace

I have a string that I'd like to get all possible `replace`-ment combinations on using the following substitutions:

```
var equiv = {
  "a": "4",
  "b": "8",
  "e": "3",
  "i": "1",
  "l": "1",
  "o": "0",
  "t": "7"
}
```

I would like to define a `String.prototype` function, something like:

```
String.prototype.l33tCombonations = function()
{
    var toReturn = [];

    for (var i in equiv)
    {
        // this.???
        // toReturn.push(this???)
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

So I could feed in something like `"tomato".l33tCombinations()` and get back:

```
["tomato", "t0mato", "t0mat0", "tomat0", "toma7o", "t0ma7o", "t0m470", ...].
```

Order is not important. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a recursive approach, that traverses the string char by char:

```js
const toL33t = { "a": "4", "b": "8",  "e": "3",  "i": "1", "l": "1",  "o": "0",  "t": "7" };

function* l33t(string, previous = "") {
  const char = string[0];
  // Base case: no chars left, yield previous combinations
  if(!char) {
    yield previous;
    return;
  }
  // Recursive case: Char does not get l33t3d
  yield* l33t(string.slice(1), previous + char);
  // Recursive case: Char gets l33t3d
  if(toL33t[char])
    yield* l33t(string.slice(1), previous + toL33t[char]);
}

console.log(...l33t("tomato"));
```

If you really need it on the prototype thats also possibl3, but I wouldn't recommend that:

```
 String.prototype.l33t = function() {
   return [...l33t(this)];
 };

 console.log("stuff".l33t());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

The idea is to loop through each character and add every combination to the accumulator. If you encounter a character which *isn't* part of `equiv`, just add the character to every item in the accumulator. If the character *does* exist in `equiv`, duplicate all the previous combinations and add another set of combinations with the `equiv[<character>]`

```js
const equiv = {
  "a": "4",
  "b": "8",
  "e": "3",
  "i": "1",
  "l": "1",
  "o": "0",
  "t": "7"
}

const input = "tomato";

const output = [...input].reduce((acc, c, i) => {
  const r = equiv[c];
  
  if (i === 0) {
    return r ? [c, r] : [c];
  }

  const updated = acc.map(a => a + c);
  const newItems = r ? acc.map(a => a + r) : [];
  
  return [...updated, ...newItems]
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Wrapped this up in a prototype function and it's blazing fast! Excellent answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could take a cartesian product for generating the wanted values.

```js
function leet(string) {
    const
        cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
        code = { a: "4", b: "8", e: "3", i: "1", l: "1", o: "0", t: "7" };

    return Array
         .from(string, c => c in code ? [c, code[c]] : [c])
         .reduce(cartesian)
         .map(a => a.join(''));
}

console.log(leet('tomatoe'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have approached this in a recursive way, on each iteration of the recursion, a new character of the string is analyzed, if this character have a replacement, then both the `character` and the `replacement` are concatenated to all previous results making a new set of results, otherwise only the `character` is concatenated to all the previous results. Note, I have abuse of the spread operator for this approach.

```js
var equiv = {a: "4", b: "8", e: "3", i: "1", l: "1", o: "0", t: "7"};

const genComb = (str, arr) =>
{
    if (!str) return arr; // Finish condition.
    let c = str[0];       // New char to be appended.
    let r = equiv[c];     // New char replacement.

    return genComb(
        str.slice(1),
        [...arr.map(e => e + c), ...(r ? arr.map(e => e + r) : [])]
    );
};

String.prototype.l33tCombinations = function()
{
   return genComb(this, [""], 0);
}

console.log("tomato".l33tCombinations());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might yield the desired result! Loop through each letter and every time a new replacement is found, add a new word to `toReturn` and make sure to search each new word!

```js
var equiv = {
  "a": "4",
  "b": "8",
  "e": "3",
  "i": "1",
  "l": "1",
  "o": "0",
  "t": "7"
}

String.prototype.l33tCombinations = function() {
  var toReturn = [this.toLowerCase()];

  for (let i = 0; i < toReturn.length; i++) {
  
    for (let j = 0; j < toReturn[i].length; j++) {
      if (equiv[toReturn[i][j]]) {
       let newWord = toReturn[i].split('');
       newWord[j] = equiv[newWord[j]];
       let newWordJoined = newWord.join('');
       if (!toReturn.includes(newWordJoined))
        toReturn.push(newWordJoined);
      }
    }
 
  }

  return toReturn;
}

console.log('tomato'.l33tCombinations());
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer as far as readability goes! Thanks for the clear answer :)

Comment: No problem! The fact that it has to use the array `includes` method bothers me and probably makes it more inefficient than the others.